# audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying function in SWIFT

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation

I am writing a simple player in swift using the AVFoundation framework. Everything seems to be working except my player keeps playing the same song over and over again.  I only have one song in my play list so this makes sense.  what I am trying to do is check the **audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying** flag to make sure it is done playing and then I will make it stop.  I am not sure how to implement the call to get the flag here is my code.

```
    mp3Player?.play()
    **if (mp3Player?.audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully) {**
    mp3Player?.stop()
 }
```

the proper way to get the flag in objective c is:

```
    - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
NSLog(@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying");
}
```

Can anyone explain how to implement the same function in SWIFT? This is my first program in SWIFT. I tried reading about void functions in SWIFT but no luck.

the error I am getting is Cannot convert value of type 'AVAudioPlayer.Type' to expected argument type 'AVAudioPlayer'

Answer (score 6):

You can cross check that while start playing the audio `numberOfLoops` set to `0` and `delegate` is set to `self` or controller where your player is playing.

```
   mp3Player?.numberOfLoops = 0
   mp3Player?.delegate = self
```

In the same class implement the `delegate` method of `AVAudioPlayer` like as shown below.

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer!, successfully flag: Bool) {
    //You can stop the audio 
    player.stop()

}
```

Comment: thank you.  It makes much more sense now.  I just added the         player.stop()       in the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying and program works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement a solution inside the mp3 player class as follows.

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer,
    successfully flag: Bool){
        if flag == true {
        ++self.numberOfLoops
        GlobalVariables.NumberOfLoops = numberOfLoops
        numberOfLoopsReq = GlobalVariables.NumberOfLoopsRequired
        player.stop()
        if numberOfLoops <  numberOfLoopsReq {
                // delay before and play
                let delay = GlobalVariables.DelayBeforeSong * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)// nanoseconds per second
                let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
                dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    self.player!.play()
                    }) 
                                             }
                                          }
```