# How to automatically change background image of a button after audio stops playing in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a voice record app using **xcode 10.2.1** ... After recording an audio, the audio is displayed in a tableview. Inside each cell I have a play button that when pressed should switch to pause. After audio finishes it should get back to play. How can I achieve this in swift?

I've tried many answers on stack but none of them met my requirements.

```
func btnPlayPressed(index: Int) {
        let audio = self.audios[index]

        if audio.isPlaying {
            AudioManager.sharedInstance.stopSound()
            self.audios[index].isPlaying = false
        } else {
            AudioManager.sharedInstance.playSound(fileName: audio.fileName)
            self.audios[index].isPlaying = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can extend AVAudioPlayerDelegate and override the function below. Then this function triggers you understand that audio finished.

```
func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
    print("Finish")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use NSNotificationCenter and listen when the audio finished playing. In that function you must be changing the image of the button. Are you using `AVPlayer`?

Comment: Yes I am using AVAudioPlayer

Comment: Check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339216/detecting-end-of-the-playback-in-avaudioplayer